# how to get embedded array's size in mongo?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Querying internal array size in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722850/querying-internal-array-size-in-mongodb)

I have a document which contains an array `category`. I just want to know how many items there are in `category`. All I could find in the documentation is how to count the number of top level documents.

```
{
 "_id": {
     "$oid": "4e73a30466ca1a1f56000001"
    },
 "category": [
     "Food",
     "Entertainment"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add new field to hande category size. It's a usual practice in mongo world.

Answer (score 2):

To find a single example element in a collection callend mycollection:

```
db.mycollection.find().limit(1)[0];
```

To get the number of elements in the arry category:

```
db.mycollection.find().limit(1)[0].category.length;
```

Or:

```
var elem = db.mycollection.find().limit(1)[0];
elem.category.length;
```

Comment: Doesn't that return the array, which I then count locally? Wouldn't it be better to somehow use the mongodb `count()` method and have the database just return the count without having the fetch the entire object and then count it locally?

Comment: Well, I did added to much stuff around the actual answer to complete it. So the short answer to your given question is only: `elem.category.length;`